# Dictionary text file

Tags: dictionary

I am writing a program that needs a list of English words as a source file for it to work. I realise that these source files are available for students writing games such as Hangman or Crossword solvers but I am having trouble locating such a source file and wonder if anyone knows how I can attain one without slowly scraping websites and building up a dictionary manually.

Comment: https://github.com/dwyl/english-words

Answer (score 261, accepted):

What about `/usr/share/dict/words` on any Unix system? How many words are we talking about? Like OED-Unabridged?

Comment: thanks ! 200000+ words, much appreciated ! `cat /usr/share/dict/words > words.txt` all the things !

Comment: If you're missing this file, you may install it on Debian/Ubuntu by typing `sudo apt-get install wbritish`

Comment: `/usr/share/dict` also contains american-english & british-english

Comment: `/usr/share/dict/words` includes words like 'timestamp' that eclipse reports as spelling error originally, which is really nice.

Comment: Does someone by chance know of a place where this can be downloaded for non-Unix systems?

Comment: @Tom Yeah, www.FreeBSD.org (install FreeBSD somewhere and boom, you have it). Otherwise I think this list is similar: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/eneko/data-repository/master/data/words.txt.

Comment: How about in Windows 10?

Comment: In case you didn't know: This will work on macOS too :)

Comment: @alyssaeliyah You can download it [here](https://gist.github.com/wchargin/8927565).

Comment:  <- only response

Answer (score 61):

For an English dictionary .txt file, you can use [Custom Dictionary](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sujithps/Dictionary/master/Oxford%20English%20Dictionary.txt).

You can also generate a list [aspell](http://app.aspell.net/create) or [wordlist](http://wordlist.aspell.net/) with own settings.

Also you can take a look at http://wordlist.sourceforge.net/

Only english words: http://www.math.sjsu.edu/~foster/dictionary.txt

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @DeanOC: I think it is fairly plain that the "essential parts" of a dictionary would be the entire dictionary. That's not practical to paste here. It's also fairly plain what the usage is: to grab words out of it. So this is not, in fact, link-only. It's a legitimate recommendation answer on a question that should be (and now is) closed.

Comment: @NathanTuggy This answer appeared in the LQP queue, and I believe that it fits the definition of a link-only answer. As a <3K rep user, my vote to delete doesn't do anything other than help bring it to the attention of someone who can.

Comment: @DeanOC: I know it appeared in LQP. I hit Looks OK, for the reasons given: basically, that "link-only" is a whole lot more subtle than "has a link but no code or quote? BURN WITH FIRE". Note that sufficient Recommend Deletion choices by even 2k users *will* delete posts. (I have personally been responsible for tipping a number of posts off the edge.)

Comment: @NathanTuggy You are naturally free to vote as you see fit. I voted to delete as I see no value in this answer if the link becomes stale.

Comment: [Consider this viewpoint](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605).

Comment: I cannot thank you enough! The Custom dictionary was exactly what i needed. It's for an AI project.

Comment: @sujith PS Do you know this custom dictionary link dictionary is published which year and if there's any copyright restriction?

Comment: The Foster dictionary is missing the word "car". That's concerning.

Answer (score 40):

Also take a look at:

- http://wordlist.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Using http://app.aspell.net/create with the settings of: `95 (insane)` `3 (seldom used)` `Strip` gives about 675K words.

Comment: Specifically http://wordlist.aspell.net/12dicts/ has various dictionary word lists, if you want something without proper names.

Answer (score 36):

http://www.math.sjsu.edu/~foster/dictionary.txt

350,000 words

Very late, but might be useful for others.

Comment: Looking at the first few, many are not regular English words.

Comment: this was no use since it was missing many simple words like sin, in, ...

Comment: Yeah, and has words like "wwwwwww". Not a word.

Comment: Beware, this link crashes my Firefox because it tries to load the whole file ahahahaha

Comment: @Andrew doesn't crash in Chrome 50.

Comment: Though some of the words are not really words, its perfect for my intended use.

Comment: lol, this isn't even english

Answer (score 12):

There's also [WordNet](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/). Its data files format are well-documented.
I used it for building an embeddable dictionary library for iOS developers ([www.lexicontext.com](http://www.lexicontext.com/)) and also in one of my apps.

Comment: Jackpot. In case anyone is looking for words mapped to their parts of speech, just download the main WordNet package.

Answer (score 10):

@Future-searchers: you can use [aspell](http://aspell.net/) to do the dictionary checks, it has bindings in ruby and python. It would make your job much simpler.