# Word game mechanics in XNA

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xna

I'm planning on making a casual word game for WP7 using XNA. The game mechanics are fine enough for me to implement but it is just the checking to see if the word they make is actually a word or not.

I thought about having a text file and loading that into memory at the start, but surely this wouldn't be possible to keep in memory for a phone? Also how slow would it be to read from this to see if it is a word. How would they be stored in memory? Would it be best to use a dictionary/hashmap and each `key` is a word and i just check to see if that key exists? Or would it put them in an array?

Stuck on the best way to implement this, so any input is appreciated.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting a text file into memory, even of a whole dictionary, shouldn't be too bad as `seth flowers` has said. Choosing an appropriate data structure to hold the words will be important.

I would not recommend a dictionary using words as keys... that's kind of silly honestly. If you only have keys and no values, what good is a dictionary? However, you may be on a good track with the Dictionary idea. The first thing I would try would be a `Dictionary<char, string[]>`, where the key is the first letter, and the value is a list of all words beginning with that letter. Of course, that array will be very long, and search time on the array slow (though lookup on the key should be zippy, as char hashes are unique). The advantage is that, if you use the proper .txt dictionary file and load each word in order, you will know that list is ordered by alphabet. So, you can use efficient search techniques like binary search, or any number of searches formulated for pre-sorted lists. It may not be that slow in the end.

If you want to go further, though, you can use the structure which underlies predictive text. It's called a Patricia Trie, or Radix Trie ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_tree)). Starting with the first letter, you work your way through all possible branches until you either:

1. assemble the word the user entered, so it is a valid word
2. reach the end of the branch; this word does not exist.

'Tries' were made to address this sort of problem. I've never represented one in code, so I'm afraid I can't give you any pointers (ba dum tsh!), but there's likely a wealth of information on how to do it available on the internet. Using a Trie will likely be the most efficient solution, but if you find that an alphabet Dictionary like I mentioned above is sufficiently fast using binary search, you might just want to stick with that for now while you develop the actual gameplay. Getting bogged down with finding the *best* solution when just starting your game tends to bleed off your passion for getting it done. If you run into performance issues, then you make improvements-- at least that's my philosophy when designing games.

The nice thing is, since Windows Phone supports only essentially 2 different specs, once you test the app and see it runs smoothly on them, you really don't have to worry about optimizing for any worse conditions. So use what works!

P.S.: on Windows Phone, loading text files is tricky. [Here](http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/88160/528881.aspx) is a post on the issue which should help you.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your phones hardware, you could probably just load up a text file into memory. The english language probably has only a couple hundred thousand words. Assuming your average word is around 5 characters or so, thats roughly a meg of data. You will have overhead managing that file in memory, but thats where specifics of hardware matter. BTW, it's not uncommon for current generation of phones to have a gig of RAM.

Please see the following related SO questions which require a text file for a dictionary of words.

[Dictionary text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4456446/dictionary-text-file)

Comment: Windows Phones have 512mb memory for standard spec, and 256 for the lower-end "Tango" spec. Should be fine anyway.

Comment: More to the point, for 256Mb Windows Phones, there's a 90Mb memory limitation.

Comment: Thanks. I could only mark one reply as the answer but I gave you an upvote too.