# How to create a Text twist game in Java

Tags: java

What should be the next step in creating a text twist game with only 4 letters? using Permulations This is the idea:  Here is my code:

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class sample {
public static void main(String[] args) {    
    String []a = new String[4];
    a[0] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input 1st character");
    a[1] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input 2nd character");
    a[2] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input 3rd character");
    a[3] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input 4th character");
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, a[0] + " " + a[1]+ " " +a[2]+ " " +a[3] + " is the Letters");
    }
}
```

the user will input 4 letters and then the program will generate any word that can be created to the inputed letter.

Comment: You'll need to 1) read in a dictionary file and store it in some data structure 2) generate permutations of the four letters 3) try each one in turn against the dictionary as you generate it 4) output the results. Which part are you stuck on?

Comment: well i dont know how the words will be created

Comment: or maybe how can i rumble the 4 letters that can create a 24 words.

if the letters are a,s,d,f then the possible outputs are

asdf
adfs
afsd
sdfa
dfas
fasd

and many more without repeating the same words

Comment: @RommelRubio: That's step 2 of Rup's comment. Have you read up on generating permutations?

Comment: oh sorry so the meaniing of generate permulations is rumble ok. i'l search for it thank you!

Comment: Try this it may help you the next step 1. http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/31datatype/TextTwist.java.html 2. http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/StdIn.java.html

Comment: is my understanding right? isn't he trying to write code for jumble word finder?

Comment: Rumble? As in the noise most commonly associated with thunder?

Comment: Goodness.  Based on the code I'm seeing, how about one JOptionPane to input all 4 letters at once.

Comment: @RommelRubio Please check the answer i gave and accept the answer if it solved your issue

Answer (score 3):

There is an effective way to solve this

1. get a text file that contain the words from a dictionary. This file
   will be used as the input file. we just need the words - dont need
   the meaning of words. and all the words should be in new line.
   assume we use this dictionary http://www.mieliestronk.com/corncob_lowercase.txt. [Alternate Words list source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4456446/dictionary-text-file)
2. we should read this file and convert it into a format easy to
   search. so we should be looking for a hash map. This map will be used as an input map.

   for each word in the dictionary

   {

   - sort the characters in the word in ascending order - this will be used as key
   - A list of words that satisfy the key above will be set a value.
   - so add this key value pair to the HashMap>

   }
3. now to find the list of words that satisfy the jumbled word,

   - get the word from the user
   - Sort the characters of the word in ascending order
   - use this sorted characters as key against the hash map generated in step 2, and retrieve the list of words satisfying that key.
4. you get your list of words