# detecting consecutive repeated letters from tweets

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection

I am doing feature selection in machine learning, where i would like to detect words like **happyyyyyyyyy**,**gooood**,**loooooooove** and replace it as happy,good,love. I tried using regex to replace consecutive repeated letters with one of the same but if I do that, Works fine with **looooooooove** -> love and fails in **goooooood** -> god. I collected a list of English words like **book**,**cool**,**chilling**,**breeze**,etc but this list is not sufficient for my dataset.  I need reference to continue , as collecting a list of words is really time consuming. Thanks for your replies.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/iZ5kC7/3

Comment: thanks for your suggestion @AvinashRaj but the same method does not work well for the words like breeeeed -> breed but the regex converts it to bred. And also for the words like **boooook** -> book, **breeeezzzze**->breeze. Can you please help me with that?

Comment: then it's hard to do with regex. How regex know this is a perfect word and this is not a perfect word..

Comment: I understand that, but can you suggest me any other way other than manually collecting words?

Comment: Just find yourself a word dictionary you can use or write/find a crawler that runs on wikipedia collecting words automatically.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4456446/dictionary-text-file might be a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

To get your reference, use the regex `(.)\1+`
 with something like `grep` to match words from a word list (take a look at [Dictionary text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4456446/dictionary-text-file) for a good place to start).

You should end up with a list of words that have consecutive letters, so you will have your reference.